# Propel Collection using column.name rather than column.phpName

Tags: php, mysql, collections, schema, propel

I want to query all persons and then convert to an associative array using the column name rather than the phpName. I know that within Php code, you should always the phpName but I'm trying to elegantly dump the contents into a form which uses snake_case. Thanks for the help.

Lets say I have this table in my schema:

```
<table name='person'>
  <column name='id' phpName='Id' /> 
  <column name='first_name' phpName='FirstName' /> 
  <column name='last_name' phpName='LastName' /> 
</table>
```

and I have the below query:

```
$people = PersonQuery::create()->find()->toArray();
var_dump($people);
```

This will give me:

```
array(1) { [0]=> 
    array(3) { 
        ["Id"]=> int(1) 
        ["FirstName"]=> string("John") 
        ["LastName"]=> string("Doe") 
    } 
}
```

but I really want this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> 
    array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> int(1) 
        ["first_name"]=> string("John") 
        ["last_name"]=> string("Doe") 
    } 
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I suppose this maybe better suited for the propel forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$people = PersonQuery::create()->find()->toArray(BasePeer::TYPE_FIELDNAME);
var_dump($people);
```

Look in the file BasePersonPeer for other options, including `translateFieldName($name, $fromType, $toType)` which is another way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late response, but appreciate the feedback